# How to directly return JSON object from $http?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to create a  `factory` that always returns the `json` object retrieved from a webservice:

```
angular.module('test').factory('myService', myService);
myService.$inject = ['$http'];

function myService($http) {
    var urlBase;

    return {
        getContent: function(id) {
            return $http.get(urlBase).then(function(response) {
                return response.data;
            });
        }
    };
}
```

When I call `MyService.getContent();`, I'm not getting the `JSON` object, but an object with `$$state` and `__proto__`.

Why? How can I fore the factory to directly return the content only?

Note: I know I could write

`MyService.getContent().then(function(response) {
   console.log(response);
});`

but this way I'd always have to repeat the `then... function` statement when I access the factory.

Comment: What happens if you open the url (urlBase) in a browser?

Comment: This is why promises are there for. How would you ensure the sequence if you won't use promsie returned by $http in controller. In case you wan't to setup some model with the data returned from service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return the result of an asynchronous function. Your `return response.data;` statement is just exiting the promise `.then()` callback. You should modify your function like so:

```
getContent: function(id) {
  return $http.get(urlBase);
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
MyService.getContent().then(function (response) {
  // do something with the response
});
```

Comment: I posted this before your edit, but it still applies - there's no way to synchronously return a piece of data that's retrieved asynchronously!

Answer (score 0):

That is because you are returning a promise that has already been resolve and not the promise instance. Just returning

```
$http.get(urlBase)
```

from your getContent function should do the trick :)